# FIR filtering using window function: implementation problem

Tags: c++, implementation, signal-processing

I want to make a FIR filter using a window function. I have some sample data and *size* variable is a count of samples. The *windowSize* variable is a size of the window function. 
At first I create the window function (blackman window): the variable *window*
Then I need to multiply it by sin(x) / x function and convolve with real data (variable *data*):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
for (j = 0; j < windowSize; ++j) {
    double arg = 2.0 * PI * ((double)j - (double)windowSize / 2.0) / (double)windowSize;
    if (i + j - windowSize / 2 < 0)
       continue;
    if (arg == 0) {
    filteredData[i] += data[i + j - windowSize / 2] * window[j] * 1.0 /  (double)windowSize;
    } else
        filteredData[i] += data[i + j - windowSize / 2] * window[j] * (sin(arg) / arg) / (double)windowSize;
    }
}
```

The problem:

1. As a result I get a filtered data with an average which very different than the average of the original data. Where is a mistake?
2. In the DSP book it is written that in order to make a FIR filter we should multiply the function sin(x) / x by a window function and then perform the convolution, but nothing is written about *x* in the *sin(x) / x*, so I used the:

   double arg = 2.0 * PI * ((double)j - (double)windowSize / 2.0) / (double)windowSize;

for the *x* value, the argument of sine, is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sin(x)/x` filter is a lowpass filter. That is, it suppresses all frequencies above a certain *cutoff* frequency.

If the sampling frequency is `Fs` (Hertz) and you want a cutoff frequency of `fc` (Hertz), You should be using `x = 2*PI*fc/(2*Fs)*n` where `n` goes from `-N` to `+N` and `N` is large enough that the sin(x)/x function is close to zero. Don't forget that sin(x)/x is 1 when x is zero.

To maintain the *average* of the signal you have to normalize the filter coefficients by their sum. I.e., set f_norm[k] = f[k] / sum(f[k], k=...)

That's all I have to say at this point. It seems like you have a lot to learn. I suggest a good book on signal processing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the implementation is concerned it looks like you need to initialise `filteredData[i]`, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    filteredData[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < windowSize; ++j) {
        ...
```